# Identify and convert fonts inside a font SuitCase

Tags: fonts, converters, fontforge

I need to **identify a font SuitCase** from PostScript 1 fonts in the same directory, both **not having an extension**, and then **convert each of the SuitCase fonts** to a `.ttf`.

```
|- Kigali [font SuitCase]
|- KigalBlo [PostScript 1 font]
|- KigalIta [PostScript 1 font]
|- KigalLx [PostScript 1 font]
|- KigalLxIta [PostScript 1 font]
...
```

The `Kigali` file opens fine in OSX, with all the font variants inside. PostScript fonts opens fine too and aren't required by the SuitCase, which is independant.

The `file` command fails to identify either of them and returns `empty`.

`fontforge` **won't even identify fonts inside the SuitCase** :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/fontforge
fonts = FontsInFile($1)
Print("Fonts inside "+$1+":")
Print(fonts)


$ ./convert.pe Kigali
Fonts inside Kigali:
[]
```

I installed `fontforge` with `brew`. Version is: `fontforge: stable 20150330`

I can't figure out how to manipulate this obscure font fomat. Anybody tried and succeed?

Comment: No, you don't: The font is commercially available in modern OpenType format (Adobe converted their entire portfolio to OpenType years ago), and I know for a fact that converting Adobe fonts for continued use yourself violates their terms of use. The entire family's $95 over on http://fonts.com/font/adobe/kigali/complete-family-pack

Comment: I used Kigali for the example, but the library counts more than 6000 fonts (not only Adobe's) that I have to convert for an internal use. I posted on StackOverflow because of a technical difficulty, not to hear that I do or don't need to convert these fonts.

Comment: Instead of getting upset about someone responding based on the text you wrote, that information would have been excellent to have put in your post from the get-go. Please update it so it doesn't look like you're asking about one, illegal to convert even for internal use, font.

Comment: You answered a question I didn't ask. I can't see why you would care wether I am allowed to convert a font or not. It doesn't help me with the technical difficulty I'm experiencing.

Comment: It matters for the same reason it matters when someone asks a question like "how do I break the tomb raider DRM, I've tried <legal utility> but the hex maps dont' work?" - even if that is allowed where you live, that's technically a question that's going to get shot down. If you have an example font in that suitcase for which the conversion (and ideally, distribution, in case you need to put it somewhere for people to test with) is legal: perfect! update your post with that, and then people will be able to help you with that.

Comment: I added an issue in its Github repo for this problem: https://github.com/fontforge/fontforge/issues/4668